# Size of multidimensional-array with a user input double value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

below is my code:

```
//variables
double sSideA,sSideB;
double incrementA,incrementB;
double eSideA,eSideB;

//obtain user input
cout << "Please enter the starting value of side A: ";
cin >> sSideA;

cout << "Please enter the end value of side A: ";
cin >> eSideA;

cout << "Please enter the increment value of side A: ";
cin >> incrementA;

cout << "Please enter the starting value of side B: ";
cin >> sSideB;

cout << "Please enter the end value of side B: ";
cin >> eSideB;

double hypo[eSideA][eSideB]; //initialize multidimensional array
```

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array with a size determined by the user input. I'm getting an error from Microsoft Visual Studio that says `hypo` must only contain constant values.

Is it possible to generate an array determined by the user's `eSideA` and `eSideB` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`

Comment: This code makes no sense, using doubles to size an array?  Overwiting input before using it? And the answer to your question is yes and no *at the same time*; there are no runtime sized multidimensional arrays in C++, but there are dozens of ways to fake it.  Consider a vector of vectors.

Comment: when asking about compiler errors, please quote them verbatim. Even if they are hard to read sometimes, they hold valuable information